# How can I execute a stored procedure with JDBC / jTDS without using a transaction?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

We run a website written in Java that uses JDBC with jTDS to access an SQL Server database.

Our database contains a complex stored procedure that typically takes 10 minutes to run. The stored procedure works fine if we execute it directly (say from SQL Server Management Studio) because it does not run in a transaction. But if we execute it using jTDS then it locks up the entire website for 10 minutes. This happens because jTDS runs it in a transaction, and so all the website requests are on hold waiting for the transaction to finish.

For example, the following locks up the website due to the transaction:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://example/example");
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("exec dbo.procTest");
callableStatement.execute();
```

Is there any way that we can run a stored procedure using JDBC / jTDS without it running in a transaction?

Please note that calling this on the jTDS connection is not valid:

```
connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_NONE);
```

That throws an exception stating that the Connection.TRANSACTION_NONE parameter is not supported by jTDS.

---

**EDIT:** I probably could have asked the question better: the core problem is not the transaction itself, the problem is that the transaction causes database locks to be held for 10 minutes. Either I need to **get rid of the transaction**, or I need **locks released during the transaction**.

Comment: "does not run in a transaction"? Are you sure? AFAIK every SQL statement runs in a transaction. The closest you can get to "no transaction" is probably auto-commit, where every statement is executed in its own session.

Comment: I can explain what I mean in practical terms: if I run "EXEC dbo.procTest;" using SQL Server Management Studio then the website doesn't lock up. But if I run "BEGIN TRANSACTION; EXEC dbo.procTest; COMMIT;" then the website locks up for the duration of the transaction — monitoring the database locks shows that website connections are all waiting on the thread executing that stored procedure.

Maybe the transaction is not the key point here. Another way I could put it is "I don't want the database to hold locks on updated objects for the duration of a transaction".

Comment: Have you tried `Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following ugly workaround. I'm still interested if anyone can explain how I might do this properly; but the workaround will do for the moment.

The database is running on the same machine on the webserver, so I am able to use the standard SQL Server command line tools to run the stored procedure. The Java code to trigger it is:

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sqlcmd -E -d \"example\" -Q \"EXEC dbo.procTest;\"");
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handler here
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Handler here
    }
```

So exactly the same stored procedure is run — the difference is that the webserver doesn't lock up because *sqlcmd* isn't running it in a single transaction. Yes it's ugly... but it's the only option I know of that works!

Answer (score 2):

In our case, the StoredProcedure had to be called, was throwing an exception when called from jtds:

> Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction.

What I found @ https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-66239
is exec call need to be prepend with "SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;"

here's what spring-based snippet looked like:

```
try {
  jdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations.execute("SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;")
  //noinspection ConvertExpressionToSAM   // we have 1.6 code version
  jdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations.call(new CallableStatementCreator {
    override def createCallableStatement(con: Connection): CallableStatement = {
      val callableStatement = con.prepareCall(
        s""" EXEC dbo.RestoreLatestCopy
           |      @ID = ?
           |""".stripMargin)
      callableStatement.setInt(1, getMappedRestoreId(fromDbName))
      callableStatement
    }
  }, parameters ++ rsParams)
} catch {
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Connection#close()` or `Connection#commit()` should submit and end the transaction. Do you close DB resources like `Connection` in the `finally` block?

Comment: Yes, Connection#close() and Connection#commit() do submit and end the transaction... which is not what I'm having a problem with. The problem is that before those lines are reached we have a 10-minute long transaction which locks up everything. So it's not a question of whether the transaction is being committed correctly, it's a question of whether I can avoid running it in a transaction in the first place.